# Location Listener Can't Reach Location

Tags: android, fragment

My app uses users location and have fragments. In main activity this fragments changes.

But there is a problem here. I implement "Location Listener" interface to my fragment class, and drop the breakpoint in "onLocationChanged" event. And program never hit the breakpoint.

Why I can not reach the users location?

**Here is my code:**

```
public class NearestCoffeeVenueFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener{
    // GPS Variables
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private  String provider;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,this);

        provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location != null){
            lastLocation = location;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.gps_success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.gps_fail),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cannotReachGpsWarning();
        }


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearest_coffee_venue, container, false);
    }

 /** LocationListener Interface Functions
     * */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Long: "+location.getLongitude()+" Lat:"+location.getLatitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        lastLocation = location;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider,int status,Bundle extras){

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.gps_enabled_provider)+provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public  void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.gps_disabled_provider)+provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        /// warning messages and buttons setted from strings file.
    private void cannotReachGpsWarning(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.gps_disabled))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.gps_enable),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                showGPSOptions();
                            }
                        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.gps_disable),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

    private void showGPSOptions(){
        Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
    }
```

As I say, I don't see any toasts or anything else. The fragment's doesn't hit the breakpoint on "onLocationChanged" function. This means fragment can't reach location. And when fragment starts, I see "Can not reach location" error even the phone's location was on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable location in the device for both sources GPS ans NETWORK? Currently in your code your'e asking for network provider, if this provider is disabled the method getLastKnownLocation will return null.

Comment: But my phone network provider on therefore we say If network provider disable and when I enable it, the program must hit the breakpoint. But it never happens.